# Azure Databricks Release Pipeline from Devops

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm currently trying to setup a release pipeline to deploy notebooks into both sandbox and prod databricks instances I have setup. I've managed to get it to the deploy part of the job however it errors with the following:

Error: cannot create job: Invalid python file reference: /Users/myworkemail/.bundle/Release Bundle/dev/files/evaluate_notebook_runs.py. Please visit the Databricks user guide for supported python references

For reference I am using this guide from microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops

I have checked in my sandbox databricks instance and I can see the files have been deployed to the server, however I don't understand why the call to the pyton file is failing as it is in the correct place.

[image]

I'm now stuck as I'm not sure how to get the deployment agent to find the files and finish the deployment. Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Glyn

Comment: It's recommended to share your DevOps pipeline definition(yaml), the error log screenshot. In addition, you can set variable `system.debug` as true in pipeline to check if there's more info.